# Overlap plot and box plots in r

Tags: r, boxplot

I have a scatter plot with x values ranging from `0.0` to `1.0`. I'd like to add one vertical box plot in correspondence of `x=0`. Do you have any ideas on how to do that?

I also thought about inverting the actions, i.e., starting from a box plot and then adding points, lines and whatever else, but in this case I need the box plot to occupy just the space above the `x=0` coordinate.

Comment: I'm not sure quite what you are asking. Maybe you could give us some data, and possibly even sketch out something on paper so we can see what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do that with base graphics.

First plot the scatter data; then compute the boxplot and specify the location using the add and at statements.

see `help(boxplot)`

Answer (score 0):

t=2k;Xk. So for box plots, y follows 2k is the vertical box plots.